# Enable Export Option In SSRS 2005 Without Using Report Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, export-to-csv

I am creating **Dynamic RDLs** without using SSRS or ReportServer. I am using `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0` and `2005 XML structure`.

My report is working fine dynamically but I am facing an issue in `Export` option. I am only able to see 3 options in my Export "`PDF, Excel, Word`", but I also need "`CSV`" under Export option.

I know there are ways to show and hide the Rendering Options under Export but all links suggest to do this by using report server. I want to achieve this in my c# code or by using ReportViewer.

Is there any possible way to do this. Please help.

Comment: The only way I know how is to modify the ReportServer's config file.

Comment: Yes, but as I already mentioned in my Question above that I am not using ReportServer, I am dynamically generating the RDL. So I don't have any config file.

Comment: What do you do with the RDL?    Doesn't it get deployed to a SSRS server?   That's the ReportServer that needs to be modified.   Not your development software.

Comment: I am not using ReportServer, I have not deployed my Rdl files on any server. I am using a library in which I just pass my dataset and the libraray dynamicaaly generated my RDL file.